# Adding custom icon in font awesome

Tags: font-awesome

I tried adding a custom icon by converting it into .svg format. I added the converted .svg icon by importing it into http://icomoon.io/app/ and downloaded as .png image. It was not the original image.It was a simple black box. Am i missing something here??

Answer (score 2):

I am doing this now. Check out this tutorial! It uses a utility called Font Custom, which from the sounds of it you might not need, but maybe the tutorial will help you get back on track.

[Create your own Font Awesome Icons](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2012/12/16/create-your-own-font-awesome-icons/)