# How do I change the card game icon?

Tags: javascript, font-awesome

```
var Cards = [
    ,
    "apple.png",
    "fa fa-anchor",
    "fa fa-bolt",
    "fa fa-cube",
    "fa fa-anchor",
    "fa fa-leaf",
    "fa fa-bicycle",
    "fa fa-diamond",
    "fa fa-bomb",
    "fa fa-leaf",
    "fa fa-bomb",
    "fa fa-bolt",
    "fa fa-bicycle",
    "fa fa-paper-plane-o",
    "fa fa-cube"
];
```

these are icons from here

```
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

How do I replace them  to my own jpeg image?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">

Comment: by using css I guess - but there's a lot more to do if you're going to keep using font-awesome elsewhere

Comment: Please refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588775/adding-custom-icon-in-font-awesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588775/adding-custom-icon-in-font-awesome)

Comment: this is the website game I am doing, https://classworrrk.neocities.org/neo.html,I want to replace these default icons, loooooooooool

Answer (score 0):

These are font awesome icons classes, they are commonly used on `<i>` tags like this, for example:

```
<i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
```

If you want to use your own images, you should think on replace `<i>` tags for `<img>` tags like this:

```
<img src="path_to_img/cube.png" height="16" width="16">
```